# What did I delete out of my .vimrc?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I was editing my .vimrc and accidentally deleted a line, but I'm not sure which line. Before if I used the 'one' colorscheme my comments would be in italics (now they are not), and my files don't have any syntax highlighting (comments are just gray, everything else is white). When using OceanicNext I get italic comments, but I still don't get syntax highlighting.

Sorry, really trying to get into vim but everytime something breaks or is "wrong" with it.

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
syntax off
" Plugin setup
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
Plugin 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-repeat'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
Plugin 'majutsushi/tagbar'
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
Plugin 'mxw/vim-jsx'
Plugin 'mhartington/oceanic-next'
Plugin 'rakr/vim-one'
Plugin 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
Plugin 'bigfish/vim-js-context-coloring'
Plugin 'othree/jspc.vim'
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on

set t_Co=256
if (has("termguicolors"))
    set termguicolors
endif

" Shifts and such
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
retab
set shiftwidth=4
set number
set numberwidth=4
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set nofoldenable
set nocompatible
set showcmd
set encoding=utf-8
set showmatch
set smarttab
set wrap
set ruler
set mouse=a
set hidden
set ignorecase smartcase
set cmdheight=1
set lazyredraw
set laststatus=2
set scrolloff=10
autocmd vimenter * NERDTree
set backspace=indent,eol,start

" Italics for the style
syntax on
colorscheme OceanicNext
set background=dark
let g:oceanic_next_terminal_italic = 1
let g:airline_theme='one'
hi Comment gui=italic cterm=italic ctermbg=0
hi htmlArg gui=italic cterm=italic
hi Function gui=italic cterm=italic
hi Type gui=italic cterm=italic
```

Comment: Let this teach you the importance of version control / backups. If you don't want to use a full-blown revision control system like Git for your configuration, have a look at my lightweight [writebackup plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1828).

Answer (score 2):

vim uses register 1-9 for deleted text. Latest deleted text is in reg 1, When another delete happens. The text in 1 got moved to reg 2 and reg 1 holds the latest delete and so on. More details `:help quote_number`

So, you might like to peek at output of `:reg` to recognize which line is the deleted one. Thereafter you can recover the deleted line using `"1p`.

`"1p` - 1 is the register and p - paste, paste the content of register 1.

Note: This will not work if the deleted data is not in the reg.

Comment: This won't work as I have edited the file more than 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

try turning syntax on, it is off on the third line

`syntax on`

if that does not work; I suggest removing:

```
if (has("termguicolors"))
    set termguicolors
endif
```

This gave me serious trouble when I first using vim on the terminal and with tmux. And my colorscheme is perfect in the terminal without it